# i use Auth component on cake php and this component don't work

Tags: cakephp, components, authentication

i use Auth component on cake php and this component don't work.

my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) default 'www',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

and my UsersController is :

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';
    var $helpers = array('Session');
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->login($this->data);
        $this->set('aya',$this->data);
        $this->Auth->loginAction= array ('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array ('controller'=>'users','actions'=>'edit','1');
        $this->Auth->deny('delete');
    }

    function login() {
    }

    function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

and my login.ctp file is :

```
if($session->check('Message.auth'))
        $session->flash('auth');
echo $form->create('User', array ('action','login'));
echo $form->input('usrname');
echo $form->input('password', array ('type','password'));
echo $form->end('Login');
```

but this is not work

why?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- beforeFilter() will be called in every request. And $this->data will have the POST data of that request, not just the login information. Is that what you want?
- You set loginRedirect to delete??
- `echo $form->create('User', array ('action'=>'login'));
  echo $form->input('username');
  echo $form->input('password', array ('type'=>'password'));`

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve so I can't tell you how to write the code. Read the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

Comment: You set loginRedirect to delete??
this is example 
i edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

can you define not working? it gives you an error? does nothing?

I think that since you are adding the auth component in the users controller only and not in the appController this will make the component to ONLY work inside User actions. And since you have only login and logout in UsersController and this functions are allowed then the component would do nothing, just make your users/login automagically work...

My suggestion is that you move this

```
var $components = array('Session', 'Auth');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->login($this->data);
    $this->set('aya',$this->data);
    $this->Auth->loginAction= array ('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array ('controller'=>'users','actions'=>'delete');
    $this->Auth->deny('delete');
}
```

to your AppController, and it should work

EDIT:

Reading again your code i see a lot of errors:

1. `$this->Auth->login($this->data);` You should not use this, read the manual, that is for MANUAL login, usually ajax based one, this will get any post data everytime you enter and do the login for all actions... so delete this line
2. `$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array ('controller'=>'users','actions'=>'delete');` are you sending the users after they login to a delete action? suggestion: try using index or something else.
3. `$this->Auth->deny('delete');` unless you put it in allowedActions or use allow('delete') before is already denied... remove this line since it is innecesary, everything is denied unless it is said otherwise

Please read [this tutorial](http://www.endyourif.com/login-system-with-cakephp-in-under-10-minutes/) so you know what are you missing and what you have extra. it SHOULD work like this :D

Comment: i have not error , and i move this section into app controller but this program don't work.

Comment: @aya i did some edits to my answer so check it out and let me know if it worked for you :D